# When is a flag marked as "disputed"?

Tags: support, flagging, flag-reviews

How much users does a flag need, before it is marked as *disputed*? Which flags are marked as *disputed*?

Suppose that a user flags an answer as "not an answer," and I mark it as invalid; then X users mark it as invalid, and Y users mark the answer as "not an answer." When is my flag marked as *disputed*?

Suppose, then, that I flag an answer as "not an answer," and somebody marks it as invalid; then X users mark it as invalid, and Y users mark the answer as "not an answer." When is my flag marked as *disputed*?

**Update:** It seems that an "invalid flag" flag can be disputed.

[image: screenshot]

What happened, in this case? Did anybody use the "invalid flag" flag against my "invalid flag"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *invalid* flag causes all flags on that post to be disputed.

Comment: I guess that an "invalid flag" flag cannot be disputed, then.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No, one "invalid" flag causes *all* flags on that post to be disputed. That includes the "invalid" flags themselves.

Comment: @mmyers That means that if I flag the original flag as invalid, and somebody is doing the same at the same time (but with the result that I am the first flagging it as invalid), then the other user flags my flag as invalid, when he meant to flag the original flag. It doesn't seem it is the expected result.

Comment: @kia No, an invalid flag means that the original flag was meant to be invalid, and causes all flags, including all invalid flags, to be disputed.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: In other words, you will never get flag weight by flagging as invalid. [Reference link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/how-should-we-handle-flag-weight-for-invalid-flags/95029#95029)